Change of value according to a sine curve with a given angle
There is a formula for calculating the x-coordinate. width is the screen width, and progressAnimation changes linearly over time from 0 to 1:
val x = width * progressAnimation

The formula needs to be adjusted so that x changes not linearly, but according to a sine curve—starting slow, then faster towards the middle, and then slowing down again at the end:
val x = width * (0.5 * (1 - cos(progressAnimation * Math.PI)))

But in this case, the speed of change of x follows the sine curve from 0 to 180 degrees, i.e., like this: 
However, I need x to change over the time not according to 0..180 sine curve, but according to 30..150 sine curve:

When progressAnimation==0 x should also be 0. When progressAnimation==1 then x should equal width. The change of x should match 30..150 sine curve pattern.
Could you please tell me where to place this data in my formula so that the change reflects this?

This is a mathematics question, not a computer programming question. The computer programming question would be how to use the math formula to move your object. (The answer to the math question is "use integral calculus.")
